# az functionapp deployment slot

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, staging

I have a resource group containing multiple function apps as follows:

[image]

These functions app only have one production slot:

[image]

I would like to add a staging on all these function apps so that during deployment (via Azure Dev Ops), it gets deployed to staging slot first. How do I do that via PowerShell commands/ARM templates? Also, what updates need to be done in order to test in staging environment before deploying to production slot?

Comment: Please check the answer and the suggestions to see if it helpful to you. Then you can sign it as a correct one to benefit others.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not sure about the Azure DevOps! Normally, I would do these changes when publishing to and testing in the Staging Slot in Azure Function App or App Service.**

***Please check if the below workaround helps to***:

In the Portal of **Azure Function App** - **Deployment Slots**, Add a Slot:
[image]

My Function App is in consumption plan, so it has limit of 2 Deployment Slots. Refer [Function App Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-functions-limits) for more information.

---

From Visual Studio, I can choose the **deployment slot** where I need to publish the Function App like below:

[image]

> Also, what updates need to be done in order to test in staging environment before deploying to production slot?

Suppose when publishing and testing the application in **staging slot**, I need to see all the request-response logs, traces and metrics. Then I would select the few configurations setting as deployment slot setting to capture staging logs like:

**Check** the ***App Insights Instrumentation Key deployment slot setting*** to get the Application Insight Logs/Traces from the staging slot:
[image]

**Note**: [Azure Functions deployment Slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots)

Comment: Thank you! Check the App Insights Instrumentation Key deployment slot setting to drive the traffic from the staging slot. By this do you mean select/unselect that checkbox?

Comment: select the checkbox!

Comment: So, if I select the checkbox, does the value from staging get swapped to production slot?

Comment: By default, the Function App is in the Production Slot. To move our function app into the Staging slot, we need to create a staging slot in the Azure Portal, and we have to deploy into it. After deploying, if you want the application performance in the form of logs, traces, requests, and responses then you need to enable the Application Insights related settings as `Deployment Slot Setting`.

Comment: Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#create-a-deployment-setting) for more information!